# Can a Connection do multiple things at once?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I've been reading about `JDBC` a bit and I have a question;

1. why is it better to have multiple connections (connection pool) instead of just having 1 connection?
2. Can a connection only do 1 thing at a time?
3. If so, what happens if you request that the connection does something while it's already doing something else?

Comment: And after reading about JDBC, do you have some ideas about these questions?

Comment: @sherb my idea is that it's better to have a connection pool because a connection can only do 1 thing at a time and instead of creating a new connection every time you can use a recycled one which requires less resources. (I'm not too sure if that is correct, which is why I asked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Connection pools are not there for single process/app to take advantage of multiple connections. According to Wikipedia:

   > a connection pool is a cache of database connections maintained so that the connections can be reused when future requests to the database are required.

   Connection pools are used when there are a large number of processes/apps running. If each process/app were to create a new database connection in the beginning of each request cycle (and to close it in the end of each request cycle), the overhead will be large.

   Instead, you can maintain a fixed number of open connections (probably on server startup) and reuse them whenever a process/app requires to query the database. And the overhead of opening and closing connections will no longer be there.
2. A connection may be [shared by multiple threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.1.1/devguide/cdevconcepts23499.html), but ultimately will be serving only one request at a given time. And developers are [encouraged to use synchronization](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.1.1/devguide/rdevconcepts600.html) and make sure that [race conditions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) would not arise.
3. Large number of undesirable things can happen if you do this. There are [pitfalls of sharing a connection among multiple threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.1.1/devguide/cdevconcepts89498.html).

   > - Committing or rolling back a transaction closes all open `ResultSet` objects and currently executing `Statements`, unless you are using held cursors.
   >
   >   If one thread commits, it closes the `Statements` and `ResultSets` of all other threads using the same connection.
   > - Executing a `Statement` automatically closes any existing open `ResultSet` generated by an earlier execution of that `Statement`.
   >
   >   If threads share `Statements`, one thread could close another's `ResultSet`.

   The [same page](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.5.1.1/devguide/cdevconcepts89498.html) lists some practices to avoid undesirable behavior:

   > - Avoid sharing `Statements` (and their `ResultSets`) among threads.
   > - Each time a thread executes a `Statement`, it should process the results before relinquishing the `Connection`.
   > - Each time a thread accesses the `Connection`, it should consistently commit or not, depending on application protocol.
   > - Have one thread be the "managing" database `Connection` thread that should handle the higher-level tasks, such as establishing the `Connection`, committing, rolling back, changing `Connection` properties such as auto-commit, closing the `Connection`, shutting down the database (in an embedded environment), and so on.
   > - Close `ResultSets` and `Statements` that are no longer needed in order to release resources.